# Spring4, RequestMapping

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I tried to implement a “Hello Word” demo with Spring 4 that maps the "/" http request to a method call. I found an example doing this but wanted to do the same from scratch. I got it running, the implementation classes (application and controller) **do not deviate from the demo** but the request mapper in my own app causes an error handler to be called. The differences in the log of the running demo and my app:

> ——>this line is missing in the bad case: [ main]
>   s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped
>   “{[/],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}”
>   onto public java.lang.String
>   com.goodvideotutorials.spring.controllers.RootController.home()

Could you please have a look at it and advise me why the request mapping does not work in my case? Thank you also in advance. The code sample I copied below:

```
Application:

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

Controller:

@RestController
public class RootController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(){
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

Comment: you omit the package names, so I have to ask: What is the package name of you `Application` and `RootController` class - make sure that `RootController` is in the same or subpacke of the package that contains the `Application` class.

Comment: Ralph, thank you a lot. This solved the problem. I moved the Application and the RootController into the same package and the request mapping worked! However, I don't know why :-) as the demo application contains them also in different packages and that works, too.

Comment: In the demo app they were in subpackages. That explains it. Thank you a lot, Ralph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spring boot applications, the Bean that are found be automatic class scanning must be located in subpackges (or the same package) of the package that contains the class that is used to start the application.